# Observable field usage with two way binding (Removing property change listener)

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-architecture-components

I am using an Observable field in a ViewModel. When the  Observable field gets updated, I change the UI visibility.

This can be done either done by

```
object : Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
                override fun onPropertyChanged(sender: Observable?, propertyId: Int) {

                }

            }
```

remove the callback in ondestroy.

**or**

directly mapping in XML like `@{}` using two-way binding.

Now the question is how do I remove the listener if using two-way binding? I know the Livedata can be a replacement for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure regarding which memory leak you are talking.

Memory leak in Java occur when one object exists long period of time and it contains strong references to other objects that should not be used anymore, thus should be destroyed by GC, but still persist because of that strong reference.

In Android specifically memory leaks usually occur when some long lasting object stores strong reference to an Activity (or in some cases Fragment). All the other memory leaks in android are not so impactful(except the ones with bitmaps - but it is a completely different topic)

So let us return to the data binding with an `ObservableField` and its callbacks inside the `ViewModel` or two way data binding via `@={}`. In most of the cases **there will be no memory leak in both of those cases**. To understand why - you will need to understand how does Android framework operates with UI and also understand now does view data binding works. So what happens when you are creating a callback via either `ObservableField` and callback or with `@={}`

When you write

```
    val someField: ObservabaleField = ObservableFiled<String>("someText")
    val someCallback = object : Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
                override fun onPropertyChanged(sender: Observable?, propertyId: Int) {

                }

    }
    someField.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(someCallback)

    // and in the layout
    android:text="@={viewModel.someField}"
```

In the generated file it does something like this

```
    androidx.databinding.adapters.TextViewBindingAdapter.setText(this.mboundView1, viewModelSomeFieldGet);

    @Override
    protected boolean onFieldChange(int localFieldId, Object object, int fieldId) {
        switch (localFieldId) {
            case 0 :
                //...
                return onChangeViewModelSomeOtherStuff(object, fieldId);
            case 1 :
                return onChangeViewModelSomeField((androidx.databinding.ObservableField<java.lang.String>) object, fieldId);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

As you can see there is no `context` neither `activity` or `fragment` leaks since there is no strong reference to them stored anywhere. There is no references to `context`, `activity` or `fragment` in your `ViewModel` either(I hope!). Moreover it works the other way around - ui stores link to the `ViewModel` in the binding implementation thus our `ViewModel` may be leaking. It is rear case since the UI of an Activity or a Fragment usually gets destroyed along with its `ActivityBindingImpl` or `FragmentBindingImpl` bindings but...

To be sure you have manual way to clear references: in either Activity' `onDestroy` or Fragment' `onDestroyView` call

```
clearFindViewByIdCache()
binding.unbind()
binding = null
// if you store view link in your viewModel(which is bad and may cause leaks) this is the perfect place to nullify it
viewModel.view = null
```

Also to handle binding auto clearing you may use [`AutoClearedValue`](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/util/AutoClearedValue.kt)

the actual usage may look like(if you don't care about its type)

```
override var binding: ViewDataBinding? by autoCleared()// that is all - no need of onDestroy or onDestroyView
```

**Edit**

If you want to manually unregister all the callbacks from your `ObservableField`s you can do it. The best way to do it is in `onCleared()` method of `ViewModel`. You should call `observableField.removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback)` to handle the stuff. It will look like this considering `ObservableField` and callback declarations above:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel{
   //ObservableField and callback declarations
   ...
   override void onCleared(){
       someField.removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(someCallback)
   }

}
```

**Edit end**

This all things I've just described ensures absence of memory leaks while using `ObservableFields` and view data bindings. It is all about a correct implementation. Of course you can implement it with leaks, but you can implement it without ones.

Comment if something is still unclear - I will try to expand the answer.

A bit more info about Fragment dependent leaks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58181389/9248201)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info.Actually my question seems to be pharased in correct was not  really focusing on memory leak (will edit the question).I was asking about the listener of onPropertyChange that gets added up  .on destroy we have remove it .But In case of two way binding we use @{ } .I hope the impl class does something like adding the property change listener. How to remove the listener.will it removed calling autoCleared()/?

Comment: You don't have to remove it - it won't cause leak. But you can if you want to. The best place to do it in `onCleared()` method of `ViewModel`. Call `someField.removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(someCallback)`. I will add this to the answer

Comment: autoCleared, in this case, only handles view binding.

Comment: I had the same problem leo added below.

Comment: You can use LiveData to have more control. Regarding ObservableFields the solution I gave you is a pretty much all you can do. Regarding multiple requests - it is not a problem of removing listeners rather than a general architecture problem.

Comment: Leo just explained that it is ok that sometimes framework does not unsubscribe completely from all the listeners and you have to know about it and create your architecture accordingly. But we cannot construct this architecture for you - it is way more out of the scope of your question. You wanted to know how and where to unsubscribe - I answered you. If you want to know how to correctly construct your ViewModel and ui bindings considering your domain usecases - ask another question and provide a lot more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `removeOnPropertyChangedCallback` function in ViewModel class. Here is how your ViewModel would look like:

```
abstract class ObservableViewModel(app: Application): AndroidViewModel(app), Observable {

@delegate:Transient
private val mCallBacks: PropertyChangeRegistry by lazy { PropertyChangeRegistry() }

override fun addOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback: Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback) {
    mCallBacks.add(callback)
}

override fun removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback: Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback) {
    mCallBacks.remove(callback)
}

fun notifyChange() {
    mCallBacks.notifyChange(this, 0)
}

fun notifyChange(viewId:Int){
    mCallBacks.notifyChange(this, viewId)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ### removeOnPropertyChangedCallback never gets called?
>
> This actually does
> get called, eventually and periodically, by the Data Binding framework
> to clean listeners that have been collected. It’s likely however, that
> your ViewModel will still have some callbacks registered when it is
> destroyed, and this is okay. The Data Binding framework uses weak
> references for the observers and it’s not required that they be
> unregistered before the ViewModel is destroyed. This won’t cause any
> memory leaks.
>
> With that said, if you rotate the phone rapidly, several times in a
> row, while on the same screen. You’ll notice
> ObservableViewModel.addOnPropertyChangedCallBack is called several
> times and if you look inside the source for
> android.databinding.ViewDataBinding, you’ll see the observer count
> does rise each time.
>
> This is where the periodic removal comes in. If you use the app long
> enough, rotate a few times, and have a breakpoint set on
> ObservableViewModel.removeOnPropertyChangedCallback. You’ll see that
> it is called periodically to clean up old observers and if you look up
> the call stack you can find more detail about where that comes from,
> how it’s triggered, etc.

You can track more at: https://caster.io/lessons/android-mvvm-pattern-with-architecture-component-viewmodels.

Hope this help you!!

Comment: Then what's the solution? Manual removal??.Because if the listeners registered getscalled 2 or 3 times .may be  i am sending 2 or 3 network requests right?

Comment: Oh..base on explain above, that mean data binding will take a weak reference and auto remove/destroy when your activity/fragment call destroyed. And about manual remove, I think you can create a `BindingAdapter`, set `null` whenever you want release. On network call, for avoid multiple call, you can use `RxJava/RxAndroid` and handle on `Disposable`. I think it is a good practice.